# Sqoop import is taking very long time for even smaller set of 3 records

Tags: import, sqoop

It's been a hour still Sqoop Import has started and it's not getting complete

command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc://localhost/testDb --username root -P --table student
```

I had been working on sqoop import for a week and when I faced this earlier, I cleared out temporary files and it was working fine. Now, the issue is occuring again.

Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-bigdata/compile/5c******/student.jar
MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
INO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of student

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places sqoop can get stuck: Scheduling in Yarn or MRv1, source database is slow, destination is slow. I'd check your MR/Yarn logs to see if the job progresses. Also, reach out to the [sqoop mailing lists](http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html) for more help.

Comment: Can you please verify the DB URI? it says only JDBC not which database.